# Mark property as foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, npgsql

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` to manage users in my WebApp. I derived an `ApplicationUser` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
    public string TgUserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have another entity let's call it `Player` which is managed by an `ApplicationUser`.

```
public string Id { get; set; }

public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

I purposely do not want to create a property of type `ApplicationUser` and have to mess around with include statements when retrieving objects from the database. I do want to have a property that holds the primary key which I then use to retrieve those objects on demand.

How can I tell EF Core that `ApplicationUserId` is a foreign key to `ApplicationUser.Id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using the fluent API. First you need to define the relationship using the appropriate `Has` / `With` call overloads, and then use the `HasForeignKey` to map the property as FK.

In this particular case (many-to-one, no navigation properties on both ends, explicit FK property) it should be something like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
    .HasOne<ApplicationUser>() // no reference navigation property
    .WithMany() // no collection navigation property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ApplicationUserId) // FK property
    .IsRequired(); // remove this if the relationship is optional
```

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) - [Manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration), [Foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key), [Required and optional relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships) sections of the official EF Core documentation.